# Comparing two tables in excel to see if columns match

Tags: excel

I have two tables with same columns.

```
Date
Amount
```

And I want to find out if Date is in table one, then look for amount if both equals then TRUE else FALSE

example

```
Table 1                  ANSWER        Table 2
Date         amount                    Date        amount
01.01.2017   100           TRUE        01.01.2017    100   
02.01.2017   200           TRUE        02.01.2017    200   
15.01.2017   1500          FALSE       15.01.2017    1000   
08.01.2017   300           FALSE        09.01.2017    300   
01.01.2017   100           TRUE        01.01.2017    100
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are really using `Table`s, and `ANSWER` is the third column of `Table1`, the formula for the `ANSWER` column is:

```
=[@Amount]=VLOOKUP([@Date],Table2,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: Just be aware that the Vlookup will only ever find the first matching date, if there are duplicates, so in the last row of the example, the amount in the 5th row in Table1 is compared with the amount of the 1st row in Table2.

Comment: @teylyn true, thanks. But the whole problem doesn't make much sense to me in case of duplicates, especially with different amounts. (Although there is a date duplicate in the OP's example).